# Replace multiple lines using sed in a bash script

Tags: macos, sed

I've a file with multiple lines. I'm looking for help to modify only these lines that are matching the regex pattern and then add some text after each result.
I use a mac but the bash script will run on linux, I don't know if it is relevant.

i.e

```
someText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |

someOthertext
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |

againSomOtherText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
```

after matching "`StringToSearch:`" I need to add "`| uk |`" after each "`| isoCode |`" so the result will be something like:

```
someText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |

someOtherText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |

againSomeOtherText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |
```

My regex is `^\s*StringToSearch:\n[^\n]+` and a full working example is available at regex101 following the [link](https://regex101.com/r/nL5BwO/1)

I can't figure out how to implement it in bash using sed.

Actually my sed looks like this: `sed -E 's,\^\s*StringToSearch:\n\([^\n]+\),| uk |,' < inputFile`

Comment: by default sed works on a line by line basis.. so you cannot match `\n` or perform multiline match without doing something extra arcane stuff.. also, regex101 is not suitable for cli tools like grep/sed/awk because regex syntax and features have huge differences

Comment: As an alternative to `sed` you could use `awk` which makes the job way easier.

Comment: Thank you all for the support, I learned useful tips about the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
$ awk '1; p~/StringToSearch/ && /isoCode/{print "    | uk |"} {p=$0}' ip.txt
someText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |

someOthertext
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |

againSomOtherText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |
```

- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of `$0` which contains current record
- `{p=$0}` saves the current record in `p` variable
- `p~/StringToSearch/ && /isoCode/` this checks if previous line contains `StringToSearch` and current line contains `isoCode`

  - if the condition is satisfied, `print "    | uk |"` will add the new content you need

As far as I know, this should work on all versions of `awk`. So mac/linux will not affect you.

If you insist on `sed`, you can use

```sh
sed '/StringToSearch/{N; s/$/\n    | uk |/}' ip.txt
```

which I tested on `GNU sed` and not sure if syntax/feature varies with other implementations. `N` command will add next line of input to current pattern space. `s/$/\n    | uk |/` will add the new content after the two lines. `sed` by default prints pattern space when `-n` option is not used.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> sed -E 's,\^\s*StringToSearch:\n\([^\n]+\),| uk |,'
> ```

- `\(...\)` saves backreference in regular regex epressions. In extended regex use `(...)`. Also you do not use anywhere the backreference.
- `\n` - `sed` parses *one line at a time*. So it can't match `\n`, unless you append multiple lines to pattern space with `N` commands.
- `\^` is strange - it matches a `^` character. There is no such character in your text...

You can match easily multi-line with GNU `sed` by using `-z` option. Note that it will load the whole file into `sed`s memory, so it will be memory consuming. Then write a proper regex that will globally match your expression.

Also not to remove replaced string, use `&` to re-restore it. Then suffix it with the string you want to add.

The commmand:

```
$ sed -z -E 's,\nStringToSearch:\n[^\n]+\n,&    | uk |\n,g' <<EOF
someText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |

someOthertext
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |

againSomOtherText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
EOF
```

outputs:

```
someText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |

someOthertext
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |

againSomOtherText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |
```

Comment: Thank you, nice example

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*StringToSearch:/{' -e n -e n -e 'i\
\ \ \ \ | uk |' -e '}' file > outputfile
```

Output:

```
someText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |

someOthertext
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |

againSomOtherText
StringToSearch:
    | isoCode |
    | uk |
```

This will match any line with optional whitespace and `StringToSearch:`, then `-e n -e n` will read two lines and clear pattern space, then `-e 'i\
\ \ \ \ | uk |` will insert a line of your choice, and `-e '}'` will close the block.

Comment: Thank you, nice example

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/StringToSearch/{n;p;s/[^| ]\+/uk/}' file
```

Match on a line containing `StringToSearch`.

Print that line and fetch the next.

Print that line and substitute `uk` for the isoCode (this line will also be printed as part of the normal sed flow).

See [here](https://asciinema.org/a/6aHL8IL3eNt8gCKchAQSNYAcb) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Bash script using
[ed line editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)
to replace / update a part of multiline text in a text file with automatically
generated content (eg: Table of contents)

**replace.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#
# github   : https://github.com/JV-conseil
# www      : https://www.jv-conseil.net
# author   : JV-conseil
#===============================================

_lines=""

for i in {1..10}; do
  _lines+=$'\n'"${i}. ""$(openssl rand -hex 12)"
done

ed -s "./sample.md" <<EOF
/## BEGIN GENERATED/+,/## END GENERATED/-d
/## BEGIN GENERATED/a
${_lines}

.
wq
EOF
```

**sample.md**

```
# How to replace part of a text file between markers with another text file?

Here is a Bash script using [ed line editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html "GNU manual for ed line editor") to replace / update a part of multiline text in a text file with
automatically generated content (eg: Table of contents) 

## BEGIN GENERATED

1. d5c10e45943b196b005771f1
2. bc56de530fbf5342d55203b4
3. 9608f31a09c2ece9c9cee4dd
4. 54e361257aecce0a937211c0
5. c4b2edf88293df0747694c37
6. a80275accc9b2bc72d55efcd
7. 3a2e2fec5da23b415569de00
8. 524655319a05e7dd1f48e6a5
9. 879d17e9e611d163e5a85b02
10. 80d311a786efcd9d01da86f6

## END GENERATED

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et libero eu nunc
dapibus volutpat. Proin eu neque eu orci volutpat bibendum...
```